# In German, should you use the present tense in a subordinate clause even when in English you are talking in the past tense throughout?

Tags: tense

> Ich brauche einen Begleiter. Ich **hatte gehofft**, dass er sich bereit **erklärt**, wenn er mich die Girlande flechten **sieht**, aber ...
>
> = "I **had hoped** he **would** step forward for the role when he **saw** me weaving the garland ..."

I have already come across several instances of this apparent tense-mismatch, but if an equivalent English sentence is anything to go by, I wonder why German prefers to express the idea in a subordinate clause in the present tense even though you are obviously talking about what has already happened in the past.

Is it simply ungrammatical to use other tenses than the present  in this subordinate clause?

Comment: Tenses in German and English follow completely different principles. What you express through the past tense in this particular example (hypothetical mood) is expressed through Konjunktiv II in German. In general, there are plenty of examples where the tense in the main and the subclause differ, but it won't be equivalent to the English use of tenses.

Comment: *Would step* is not past tense, and I am no expert in English grammar, but *saw* also feels more like an ersatz subjunctive than a past tense to me here.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich brauche einen Begleiter. Ich **hatte gehofft**, dass er sich bereit **erklärt**, wenn er mich die Girlande flechten **sieht**, aber ...

This is correct spoken German. In written German, you would probably use the indirect speech (*dass er sich bereit erkläre*) instead.

The part *Ich hatte gehofft* is enough for making the rest of the sentence happen in the past. The rest of the sentence is:

> Er **erklärt** sich bereit, wenn er mich die Girlande flechten **sieht**.

In this subsentence, both actions happen at the same time, therefore they use the same tense.

Comment: Eh, Konjunktiv would sound very odd here, since this isn't Indirekte Rede.

Answer (score -2):

It has to either read

> Ich hoffte, er würde sich bereiterklären, als er mich die Girlande flechten sah, …
>
> Ich habe gehofft, er würde sich bereiterklären, als er mich die Girlande hat flechten sehen, …

First is writing, latter is speech. The meaning is the same.

The example you found is a triple-fault. She used Plusquamperfekt though she explicitely talks about the same time (this is marked by using *wenn*), then she used Indikativ instead of Konjunktiv and last, she used Präsens instead of Perfekt or Präteritum. **Setzen, sechs.**

I think the obvious problem the writer had she didn't want to use *wenn* in a temporal fashion. In that case, you are required to use present tense because the non-temporal use of *wenn* works with a steady-state condition. However, this isn't possible here because things you do once, as written by herself, are never steady-state.

A possible sentence using a steady-state conditional *wenn* would be:

> Ich hoffte, er würde sich bereiterklären, wenn er sieht, wie ich **immer** schufte.

*Immer* makes a thing recurrent or steady-state. Using past tense with *immer* is also possible but means a recurrent action which is explicitely over.

> Ich hoffte, er würde sich bereiterklären, wenn er sah, wie ich **immer** schuftete.

Comment: Das Beispiel für "korrekt gesprochenes Deutsch" halte ich für sehr unrealistisch. Wenn man sowas in normalem Sprechtempo hört, versteht das doch niemand.

Comment: Es geht hier nicht um "korrekt gesprochenes Deutsch", sondern um den Unterschied in den Tempora. Schriftlich ist Präteritum, mündlich ist Perfekt. Das muss man Englischsprechern meiner Erfahrung nach immer wieder erklären, bis sie es gefressen haben. Und gerade hier, in einer Frage, in der es um Zeitformen geht, bietet sich das doch an.

Comment: This answer is hopelessly wrong. There is nothing wrong with using Plusquamperfect in the main sentence, it is correct to use Präsens for the subclause, and it is at least debatable if Indikativ or Konjunktiv should be used. Just figure that the phrase might end with "... aber er ging vorbei und nahm mich gar nicht wahr."

Comment: Das steht da aber nicht. Es nützt überhaupt nichts über hypothetische Sätze nachzudenken. Stattdessen sollte man sich mit dem beschäftigen, was gefragt ist.

Comment: Da die Frage deutlich macht, **dass** der Satz noch weitergeht, aber das Ende weglässt, bleibt uns gar keine andere Möglichkeit, als Hypothesen aufzustellen. Mein Vorschlag ist eine (für mich ziemlich offensichtliche) Möglichkeit, den Satz korrekt zu beenden, und dann sehe ich keinen Grund, eine andere Version zu erfinden, die den Anfang falsch werden lässt. Interessant im Sinne der Frage wären nur weitere Versionen, die mit dem gegebenen Anfang korrekt sind, sich aber auch mit anderen Zeitformen ausdrücken lassen.

Comment: »… aber er ist halt nicht der Typ dafür.« Das ist genauso spekulativ wie deine Variante, erlaubt aber Plusquamperfekt **nicht**. Genausowenig wie Präsens sich bereits im gefragten Satz mit Plusquamperfekt vereinen lässt.

Comment: Der Satz im OP ist doch völlig richtig. Er/sie hatte zu einem vorhergehenden Zeitpunkt (Plusquamperfekt) gehofft, dass er sich bereit erklärt, er hat sich zu einem späteren vorhergehenden Zeitpunkt (Perfekt oder Präteritum) offenbar nicht bereit erklärt und jetzt (Präsens) braucht er/sie deswegen immer noch einen Begleiter.